# Linked List, not getting previous returned

Tags: c++, linked-list

I have created a linked list which works when I add to the front of the list, or the back. I print them off and everything looks good. Then i removed from the front of the list (pop_front) and for some reason the line `temp = head->getPrevious();` (List.cpp) returns value 0x000000 so obviously it is not actually getting the pointer to the previous node. I have stepped through it and I can not see anything. Any help will be great!

Main.cpp

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "List.h"



int main()
{

    List partsList;

    partsList.push_front(22);
    partsList.push_front(25);
    partsList.push_front(32);
    partsList.push_back(100);

    partsList.display();
    cout << "now we are going to remove the first item in the list" << endl;
    system("PAUSE");

    partsList.pop_front();

    partsList.display();

    system("PAUSE");
    cout << "now we are going to remove the LAST item from the list" << endl;

    partsList.pop_back();

    partsList.display();

    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}
```

List.h

```
#pragma once
#include "node.h"
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
class List
{

private:
    int listSize;
    Node* n;
    Node* temp;
    Node* head;
    Node* tail;

public:
    List();
    void push_front(int);
    void push_back(int);
    void pop_front();
    void pop_back();
    void display();

    ~List();
};
```

List.cpp

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "List.h"


List::List()
{
}

void List::push_front(int dat)
{
    if (listSize == 0) {

        n = new Node;
        n->setData(dat);
        listSize++;
        temp = n;
        head = n;
        tail = n;

    }
    else {

        n = new Node;
        n->setData(dat);
        listSize++;
        temp = head;
        head = n;
        n->setNext(temp);
        n->setPrevious(nullptr);
        temp->setPrevious(n);
        temp = n;
    }

}

void List::push_back(int dat)
{
    if (listSize == 0) {

        n = new Node;
        n->setData(dat);
        listSize++;
        temp = n;
        head = n;
        tail = n;
    }
    else {

        n = new Node;
        n->setData(dat);
        listSize++;

        temp = tail;
        temp->setNext(n);
        n->setPrevious(temp);
// SET NEXT TO NULL
        temp = n;
        tail = temp;
    }
}

void List::pop_front()
{
    temp = head->getPrevious();
    delete head;
    head = temp;
    listSize--;

}

void List::pop_back()
{
    temp = tail->getPrevious();
    delete tail;
    tail = temp;
    tail->setNext(nullptr);
    listSize--;

}

void List::display()
{

    Node* test = head;
    for (int i = 0; i < listSize; i++) {
        cout << test->getData() << endl;
        test = test->getNext();
    }

}


List::~List()
{
}
```

Node.h

```
#pragma once
class Node
{
private:
    int data;
    Node* next;
    Node* previous;

public:
    Node();
    int getData();
    void setData(int);
    void setNext(Node*);
    void setPrevious(Node*);
    Node* getPrevious();
    Node* getNext();
    ~Node();
};
```

Node.cpp

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "Node.h"


Node::Node()
{
}

int Node::getData()
{
    return data;
}

void Node::setData(int dat)
{
    data = dat;
}

void Node::setNext(Node* nextNode)
{
    next = nextNode;
}

void Node::setPrevious(Node* prev)
{
    previous = prev;
}

Node * Node::getPrevious()
{
    return previous;
}

Node * Node::getNext()
{
    return next;
}





Node::~Node()
{
}
```

Comment: **Too**. **Much**. **Code**. Learn how to debug!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In `List::pop_front()` you are calling `head->getPrevious();`, which is obviously returning `nullptr`, and set that as the new head of the list. It should be `getNext()`.

Btw: You should not store temporary variables like n and temp in the List object. They are not needed outside of your manipulation methods and will only bloat up the object.

Comment: I am embarrassed I even had to ask that! Thanks for pointing it out, might be time for a lunch break.